# spring-data-rest return multiple projections at once (compose projections)

Tags: spring-data-rest, hateoas

Is there possibility to compose multiple projections? Is it best approach for my use case?

I have these projections for CarInBazar class for example:

- SimpleCarInList
- WidgetForHotSale
- NumberOfItemViews
- FullCarData
- CarMainImage
- CarMainImageIconSize
- CarAdditionalImages

And frontend is now making some UI page, which requires some of these projections.

Should I do:

1. frontend will do multiple requests for same resource with different projections
2. Implement Projection for each screen of frontend (duplicating things like NumberOfItemViews calculation,...)
3. Use inheritance and make specific projections utilizing `extends` keyword. i.e.:

```
    @Projection(name = "screen-dashboardHome", types = {CarInBazar.class})
    public interface DashboardHomeProjectionForCarInBazar extends SimpleCarInList,
        WidgetForHotSale, CarMainImageIconSize {
    }
```

4. Is there any possibility to request more projections at once? It could be than rendered in UI using provided profiles perhaps.

EDIT: as requested, providing projection definition example:

```java
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.Projection;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Projection(name = "CarMainImage", types = {CarInBazar.class})
public interface CarMainImage {
    Date getLastUpdateDate();

    Image getMainImage();

    default String getMainImageAdditionalInformation() {
        final var updated = this.getLastUpdateDate().getTime();
        final var created = this.getCreatedAtDate().getTime();

        if (created >= (updated - 10 minutes)) {
            return "some business logic on not published fields";
        } else {
            return "could happen not only in spel";
        }
    }
}
```

Many projections does not contain any business logic and are only filtering fields.

Comment: Without seeing the way projections are defined and actual entities there is no easy way to help you.

Comment: Hi @Aivaras, I have edited question with sample projection from project. PS: Is there any other method how to provide projections other than https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts ?

Comment: I do usually write a `@Query` in a repository if it involves one or two entities with additional interface that maps back result set. In your case we see list of names for projections but it is not clear if all of those are of the same entity.

Comment: Yes, as I stated on second line of answer, all of them (projections) are for single model (resource).

Comment: @Aivaras, please have a look at my own answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549851/11152683 ) and perhaps post your own, how you use `@Query` approach to this problem. I find your approach as best for my case (despite, I do not like so much binding without compiler time check, i.e. JPQL as string).

Comment: @Aivaras how do you expose your custom query in method returning custom DTO (instead of repository entity) in hal+json format?

Comment: not sure what you mean, could you ask a separate SO question instead of using comment thread?

Comment: I have clarified my primary objections in separate question, as @Aivaras had suggested. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622337/using-arbitrary-query-as-projection-in-spring-data-rest-project

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple projections seems to not be supported (or widely supported or easy). Using suggestion from @Aivaras comment I have used this approach:

Repository code with custom JPQL query:

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface SomeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Some, Long> {
    Page<Some> findByNameContaining(String namePart, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("select new sk.qpp.documents.projections.SomeCustomViewByQuery(s.name, s.startDate, s.endDate, s.goLiveDate, 42) from Some s where s.id = :id")
    Optional<SomeCustomViewByQuery> getByIdProjectedForSpecialScreen(Long id);
}
```

And class `SomeCustomViewByQuery` is just simple DTO like thing. Using lombok it can look like:

```
@Value
public class SomeCustomViewByQuery {
    private String name;

    private Date startDate;

    private Date endDate;

    private Date goLiveDate;

    // TODO make SomeHealth to be enum and specific logic behind it.
    String getSomeHealth() {
        final var start = this.getStartDate().getTime();
        final var end = this.getEndDate().getTime();
        final var goLive = this.getGoLiveDate().getTime();
        final var now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (now < start) {
            return "not started yet";
        } else {
            if (now < end) {
                return "work in progress";
            } else {
                if (now < goLive) {
                    return "passed end, but before goLive";
                } else {
                    return "something after goLive time";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int unicornsCount;
}
```

This way, I can make hand-crafted query (JQPL) and also create custom DTO instance. It is handy, where I need to do some joins to other tables with aggregation (count, avg, max, min, ...) and other things, which are better done on database side.